# How to sign ERC20 transaction with trezor connect

Tags: trezor

I sent some ERC20 token to an ethereum address in my trezor and I can successfully see it using MEW. I wish to use this as an air-gapped wallet but with frequent use (i.e, not cold wallet).

Suppose I create a raw transaction, how do I call trezorconnect to sign it?

[Edit: The method might be to call signtx in trezor and have crypto elements v,r,s returned and then somehow convert to format ready for broadcast. If correct, code please?]

Comment: If you have the v, r, s values and the unsigned transaction (in raw hex, RLP encoded), you need to insert those values into the RLP structure and this will give you the signed transaction. I was unable to find code that performs this operation though. If you have time, you might be able to write that function yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you have the R,S,V, using the ethereumjs-tx library:

```
let signedTransaction = _.clone(unsignedTransaction)

signedTransaction.r = Buffer.from(rsv.r, 'hex')
signedTransaction.s = Buffer.from(rsv.s, 'hex')
signedTransaction.v = Buffer.from(rsv.v, 'hex')

let tx = new ethTx(signedTransaction);
const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
const rawTx = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');
```

Then you send the rawTx with:

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTx)
```

Note that when you're signing transactions with ledger (probably also with trezor), you have to put the chain id inside the "v" **before signing** ,like this:

```
transactionCopy.v= "0x0" + chainId.toString(16)
transactionCopy.r="0x00"
transactionCopy.s="0x00"
```